# ¿Como fijar un footer en la parte inferior con CSS responsive?

Tags: html, css3

Tengo un `footer` el cual le he puesto el siguiente estilo:

```
 <footer class="page-footer white" style="position: relative;bottom: 0%;width: 100%">
```

Cuando la pantalla esta completa el footer se fija en la mitad de la pantalla pero cuando minimizo el tamaño de esta tipo `responsive` ya se queda fija en la parte inferior...

Si uso `position: absolute` se queda en a parte inferior pero si hay un scroll en la vista, al bajar se pierde la posicion e igualmente si uso la `position: fixed`...

Agradeceria su colaboración.

Comment: ¿Quieres un sticky footer? osea el footer siempre visible y cuando halla scroll se mantenga visible pero en la parte inferior de la página?

Comment: si, exactamente, simplemente que se quede en la parte inferior y mantenga la distancia sin importar el tamaño de la pantalla, porque el otro problema que tengo es que me si tengo un texto largo me le oculta una parte

Comment: Hola @Daniel tienes dos respuesta muy buenas a tu pregunta deberías seleccionar la respuesta que soluciono a tu pregunta saludos :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

te acabo de hacer un fiddle, creo que lo que te faltaba era declarar el html y el body en 100% asi:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Puedes verlo [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/3w6LLuuu/)

Comment: excelente gracias.